# TypeError django context using custom class

Tags: python, django

I am new to python and django, and I am trying to pass a class to my `RequestContext` in a template. So I have this code:

```
context = RequestContext(request, {
    'test' : myClass,
})
```

And myClass is an instance of this:

```
class ajax_user_session():
    user_model = None
    user_settings = None
    time_login = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Both `user_model` and `user_settings` are classes derived from django's `models.Model` (assigned before creating and using the context class). I get the following error:

```
TypeError at /settings
<playground.ajax_processing.ajax_user_session instance at 0x263fab8> is not JSON serializable
```

Does somebody know how to solve this, please? I can assign "normal" variables like strings, integers, but I don't want to add several things to the dictionary, I just want to use one big class.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you really trying to pass a class, or an instance of a class?

Comment: @PlatinumAzure Instances.

Comment: Where are you serialising to json?

Comment: @DanielRoseman No idea, as I said, I am pretty new to python..

Comment: What? You have written this code, no one else. The error says it is happening in the course of JSON serialisation. So, please show that code. You should be showing the full traceback and all the relevant code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
context = RequestContext(request, {
    'test' : model_to_dict(myClass),
})
```

Sometime `model_to_dict` has problems with `datetime`, so you may need to exclude that field with `model_to_dict(myClass, exclude=time_login)` and then set that manually.